# i cant able to add on touch event in my livewallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I'm an newbie to android. I just know basics of android and I'm developing a live wallpaper application! I went through developer.android.com. But I haven't got thro'
I would be really appreciable if you suggest me how to do this with a Project!

Answer (score 0):

The `android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService.Engine`

```
onTouchEvent() - called when the user performs touch-screen interaction with the window that is showing the wallpaper
onCommand() – called to process a command
```

*To react to touch events, simply implement `onTouchEvent()`. Finally, applications can send arbitrary commands to the live wallpaper. Currently, only the standard home application sends commands to the `onCommand()` method of the live wallpaper:*

Have a look on the following tutorial

[How a live wallpaper works](http://android10.org/index.php/articlesuserinterface/256-live-wallpaper-example)